# "Largest" finite-dimensional Lie subgroups of Diff(S^n), are they known?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

The group $Diff(S^n)$ ($C^\infty$-smooth diffeomorphisms of the $n$-sphere) has many interesting subgroups.  But one question I've never seen explored is what are its "big" finite-dimensional subgroups?

For example, $Diff(S^n)$ contains a finite-dimensional Lie subgroup of dimension $n+2 \choose 2$, the subgroup of conformal automorphisms of $S^n$.  Similarly it contains a compact Lie subgroup of dimension $n+1 \choose 2$, the isometry group of $S^n$.

Is it known that:

1) A finite-dimensional Lie subgroup of $Diff(S^n)$ having dimension at least $n+2 \choose 2$ is conjugate to a subgroup of the conformal automorphism group of $S^n$ ? (Answer, no, see Algori's answer below). Modified question: As Algori notes, $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R) / \mathbb R_{>0}$ acts on $S^n$ and has dimension $n^2+2n$. So is a finite-dimensional Lie subgroup of $Diff(S^n)$ of dimension $n^2+2n$ (or larger) conjugate to a subgroup of this group?

2) A compact Lie subgroup of $Diff(S^n)$ having dimension at least $n+1 \choose 2$ is conjugate to a subgroup of the isometry group of $S^n$ ? (Answer: Yes, see Torsten Ekedahl's post below)

For example, arbitrary compact subgroups of $Diff(S^n)$ do not have to be conjugate to subgroups of the above two groups -- perhaps the earliest examples of these came from exotic projective and lens spaces.  But I have little sense for how high-dimensional these "exotic" subgroups of $Diff(S^n)$ can be.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make big Lie groups act effectively on small manifolds by cheating: make the group a product of groups, with each factor acting by compactly supported diffeomorphisms on a different disjoint open subset. So the additive group $\mathbb R^N$ becomes a subgroup of $Diff(S^1)$ by flowing along $N$ commuting vector fields supported in $N$ disjoint arcs.

(added later) A similar cheat: let $a_1,\dots ,a_N$ be linearly independent functions of one variable. Then $a_1(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\dots ,a_N(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are independent commuting vector fields in the $x,y$ plane. Modify this example to make it compactly supported if you like.

(added still later) My proposed extension of the first cheat to a semisimple group (comment thread of Torsten's answer) is doomed: Choose a point on the circle and choose an element of SL_2(R) that fixes this point and acts on the tangent space there with eigenvalue c>1. Lifting the group element to the universal covering group in the right way, you get an element g of the latter group that fixes all the points above the given point in the universal covering space of the circle, in each case with eigenvalue c. But now if this line with this action could be embedded in a longer line with trivial action outside then there would be a sequence of fixed points of g with eigenvalue c converging to a fixed point of g with eigenvalue 1, contradiction.

Comment: What a shameful trick. +1.

Comment: Thanks for just pointing out my error in the problem on hemispheres. I quickly deleted my answer. I had best add to my list of personal safety precautions: attempt to write out a given problem or instance of it on paper before answering.

Comment: Tom -- that's beautiful. But can one make it work for non-abelian groups?

Comment: @algori: You can use tubular neighborhoods of smaller spheres to get subgroups of copies of the group of paths $P(SO_k)$ with pointwise multiplication.

Comment: @Scott: finite-dimensional groups of paths in $SO_k$?

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure if you're clarifying what I said, or expressing skepticism that interesting cases of such groups exist (or both).  In any case, I meant finite-dimensional groups of paths, and I don't know if there are interesting nonabelian examples.

Comment: @Scott: I meant are there interesting nonabelian examples.

My first cheat can be done with a semisimple, group, too: Make a compactly supported action of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^3$ by embedding the manifold $SL_2(\mathbb R) suitably as an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ and extending the translation action by the identity. Now in a $3$-manifold make lots of disjoint copies of this so that the product of lots of copies of the group acts.

I can see how to work my second cheat for nilpotent groups.


Comment: Oh hell, I don't know how to fix the html or TeX in a comment.

Comment: @Tom: It isn't clear to me that your proposed action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^3$ will even be continuous, let alone smooth. For problems with continuity consider the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ on the open unit disc, its continuous extension to the boundary acts non-trivially on the boundary and hence can not bne continuously extended by the identity on the complement. In fact, $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ has $S^1$ as a subgroup so we have a bound on the number of factors of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ that can act on $S^n$ (by the argument I gave).

Comment: I see, I was too hasty. 

Comment: Tom -- a small remark concerning the trick: if $X$ is a vector field on the line, then the restrictions of the fields that commute with $X$ to any connected interval where $X\neq 0$ form a 1-dimensional vector space. So the second trick is probably not so different from the first.

Comment: remark concerning the second trick, that is..

Comment: I do see the two tricks as related. 

Comment: Here's one fact:  any finite-dimensional Lie algebra of 
vector fields on a connected manifold that has
first order contact to the 0 vector field at at least one point
is nilpotent.  A similar statement is true for any topological group
action as a group of smooth diffeomorphisms.

Since this topic has scrolled off consciousness of MO, I won't say
too much more. This is part of the "generalized Reeb stability 
theorem" that I proved.  

Answer (score 22):

For 2) I think the following is an answer: Suppose $K$ is a compact Lie subgroup
of $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$ of dimension $\geq{n+1\choose 2}$. Being compact it is
the group of isometries of some Riemannian metric of $S^n$ and we fix one such
metric. The stabiliser of a point therefore has dimension at most $n\choose 2$
(the dimension of the orthogonal group of $\mathbb R^n$) and as an orbit has at
most dimension $n$, $K$ has at most dimension $n+{n\choose 2}={n+1\choose 2}$
and hence we have equality. This means that the stabiliser contains
$\mathrm{SO}_n$ and $K$ acts transitively. In particular the metric fixed by $K$
has constant curvature and then the curvature is positive and thus up to a
constant conformal factor is conjugate to the standard metric. This gives a
conjugation of $K$ into the isometry group of the standard sphere.

**Addendum**: Tom's example gives that the dimension of a non-compact group
acting (faithfully) on $S^n$ is unbounded. One question seems to remain namely
if the dimension of a semi-simple group action is bounded or not. By the above
we get a bound on the dimension of a maximal compact subgroup. In many cases
this seems to bound the dimension of the group itself. For instance, is the
dimension bounded if the center is finite? In that case the situation is
completely described by a Cartan decomposition of the Lie algebra and the
question is whether the $-1$-part (usually denoted $\mathfrak p$) of it has
dimension bounded by the dimension of the $+1$-part (the Lie algebra of the
maximal compact). I myself don't know enough of the real Lie group theory to
decide that.

An example beyond that is the universal cover $G$ of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$.
It is contractible and has no non-trivial compact connected subgroup. It also
acts on the universal cover of $S^1$ (compatibly with the projective action of
$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ on $S^1$) and hence acts continuously on $[-1,1]$
(say) fixing the endpoints. However, the action at the endpoints is not flat so
this action does not extend to a smooth action on $\mathbb R$ acting as the
identity outside if $[-1,1]$. If it could be modified to do so one could use
Tom's argument to get an action of any finite product of copies of $G$ (at least
on $S^1$). One could try to find three vector fields with support in $[-1,1]$
fulfilling the defining relations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ but it looks
tricky to me.

**Addendum 1**: To be more precise about the action on $[-1,1]$ we may use
$\tanh$ as diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $(-1,1)$. The rotation group of
$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ lifts to the group of translations of $\mathbb R$ and
they correspond under this diffeomorphism to $\varphi_\lambda(t)=(\lambda t+1)/(t+\lambda)$ of
$(-1,1)$ for $\lambda>1$ or $\lambda<-1$ (we miss the identity map which corresponds to
$\lambda=\pm\infty$). Now, one possibility of getting an action of $G$ on $\mathbb R$ which
is the identity outside of $(-1,1)$ is by trying to conjugate the one we have by
a diffeomorphism $\gamma$ of $(-1,1)$. This requires every conjugate
diffeomorphism to be *flat* at $\pm1$ where a diffeomorphism $\psi$ of
$(-1,1)$ is flat at $1$ if $\psi(x)=x+\mathcal{O}(|x-1|^n)$ for all $n$ and $x$
close to $1$ (and similarly for $-1$). Now suppose that we have a $\gamma$ such that
conjugating the given action of $G$ by it gives an action all of whose elements
are flat. In particular we have $\gamma(\varphi_\lambda(\gamma^{-1}(x)))=x+\mathcal{O}(|x-1|^n)$
for all $n$. In particular, putting $n=2$ we get that
$\lim_{t\to1}\gamma'(\varphi_\lambda(\gamma^{-1}(t)))\varphi_\lambda'(\gamma^{-1}(t))\gamma'(\gamma^{-1}(t))^{-1}=1$
and putting $s=\gamma^{-1}(t)$, using that $\lim_{t\to1}\gamma^{-1}(t)=1$ and that
$\lim_{s\to1}\varphi_\lambda'(s)=\varphi_\lambda'(1)=(\lambda-1)/(\lambda+1)$ this gives
$\lim_{s\to1}\gamma'(\varphi_\lambda(s))/\gamma'(s)=(\lambda+1)/(\lambda-1)$. This puts a very stringent
condition on $\gamma$ and then also the same condition must be fulfilled for
$\varphi_\lambda$ replaced by any element of $G$ (as well as needing the flatness
condition for all orders $n$).

Comment: Ah, of course.  I wonder if the non-compact case has a similar flavour, perhaps by getting a grip on "the" maximal compact subgroup of the Lie subgroup in question. 

Comment: Maybe I am missing something simple, but how do you show constant curvature?

Comment: Once we have that $K$, of dimension $n(n+1)/2$ acts by isometries on an $n$-dimensional manifold, we can prove that the curvature is constant in the following way.  On a riemannian manifold, Killing vectors are sections of the vector bundle $TM \oplus \mathfrak{so}(TM)$ of rank $n(n+1)/2$, relative to the connection defining the so-called Killing transport.  This bounds the dimension of Killing vectors above by the rank of the bundle, with equality if and only if the connection is flat.  Computing the curvature of the connection yields the constant sectional curvature of the manifold.

Comment: My argument was that $\mathrm{SO}_n$ acts transitively on $2$-planes so if the stabiliser of a point contains it the curvature is necessarily constant.

Comment: Since every non-compact simple real Lie algebra has exactly one non-compact simple root, $\dim G\leq 3\dim K,$ with equality only for $g=sl(2,R).$   

Comment: @Victor: Great! I was hoping for a linear bound...

Comment: "it looks tricky to me"

But it's not. Doesn't this work? Take those three vector fields on the universal covering space of the circle and transport them to the interval (-1,1) using a diffeomorphism. If the diffeo is chosen appropriately then near the endpoints of the interval they will all go to zero fast enough that they extend by zero to smooth vector fields on the line. 

Comment: @Tom: You may be right but I don't see it myself. Don't you just conjugate the group action on the interval by a diffeomorphism? Why wouldn't then the same argument show that the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ on the open unit disc could be conjugated to extend to the sphere being the identity map outside of it? We know that this is not true.

Comment: Because it's 1-dimensional. You can choose the diffeomorphism (from the 1-manifold with given action to the chosen interval) such that it squashes vectors -- makes them very short. If you try the same thing in higher dimensions you are free to squash as drastically as you wish in the radial direction, but that alone is not good enough.

Comment: @Tom: I agree that $1$-dimensionality seems to make some difference. I still don't understand your argument however and have added a discussion of my problems above (as it was too long to put in a comment).

Comment: OK, it's harder than I thought. I don't see how to do it.

Comment: I was being cavalier, making vector fields small without bothering to make their derivatives small. In fact it can't be done. This is too long for a comment, so I'll add it to my answer.


Comment: So, which Lie groups $G$ are capable of acting nontrivially on a connected manifold while acting trivially on a nonempty subset thereof? $\mathbb R$ yes. Compact groups no, because the interior of the fixed point set is always closed, because around any fixed point there is a chart in which the action looks linear. Semisimple groups, maybe no for the same reason? 

Comment: (nonempty open subset, I meant)

Answer (score 14):

The quotient of $GL_{n+1}(\mathbf{R})$ by the positive scalars acts on $S^n$; it has dimension $n^2+2n$, so for $n>1$ the answer to the first question is no. For $n=3$ an alternative proof would be as follows: there are 3-manifolds that admit a projective structure, but no M\"obius structures, as explained in Agol's answer here: [Möbius and projective 3-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23567/mobius-and-projective-3-manifolds).

By the way, the answer seems to have been updated since I last looked there and it now contains an argument which can give a classification of maximal Lie groups acting smoothly and faithfully on manifolds of given (finite) dimension.

Comment: Ah, okay. Between Torsten's answer and yours, my original question is answered.   I guess the next step would be to ask if the group above is maximal.  Hmm...